# Is this a Hurricane or Spitfire?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can anyone identify the fighter here in this picture taken from a Dornier-do17?

[image]

From: https://stukablr.tumblr.com/post/145040185970/a-pic-took-it-from-a-donier-do17-a-hurricane

Comment: Note the link states its a hurricane.

Comment: Sadly, many a German airman's last words.

Answer (score 12):

Relative thickness of the airfoil, thickness repartition over span, and low dihedral angle of the entire wing, tells it's a Hurricane.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @qq jkztd's very good answer, I'd like to add that the Spitfire never had a such a wide oil radiator under the fuselage. That to me was the dead giveaway that it was a Hurricane. Quite a durable but honestly lackluster fighter.

Comment: Yes, all the silhouettes I can quickly find of Spitfires have the radiator under one or both wings, not under the fuselage.

Comment: Try looking at the illustration on the [Spitfire Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermarine_Spitfire): all Spits had radiators under the fuselage, Hurricanes did not.

Comment: @TimLymington that is clearly false - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermarine_Spitfire#/media/File:Spitfire_mk2a_p7350_arp.jpg vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Hurricane#/media/File:Hurricane_in_planform_arp.jpg

Comment: @Jihyun But fairly well on par with the Do.17, designed around the same time. Also it was way easier and cheaper to build than a Spit, which was significant with wartime resources and serious technical problems with the Spitfire. Spitfires simply weren't ready in numbers by 1940.

Comment: Yes the small inlet there is for the carburetor air intake. It's really a simple matter of googling and checking various sources. And it's quite obvious. No radiator is that small XD. @Graham yes the Hurricane was sufficient for defense of the British Isles, but that was it. A point and shoot interceptor with little future except for limited recce and ground attack (which I admit it was adept at). I obviously have bias for the beautiful Spit.

Comment: @Jihyun Me too. :) But it's a bit like saying a Tornado wasn't a Jaguar, or an F-15 wasn't an F/A-18.  It was state of the art at the time it was designed, but it eventually became obsolete.

Comment: @TimLymington The small narrow central bulge under a Spitfire is the engine air intake and filter. The radiators were under the wings.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Hurricane.  No Spitfire of any Mark had a radiator under the fuselage, whereas every Hurricane, from the prototype to the "Last of the Many" did.  And that is NOT a carburetor (carburettor in British English) air inlet.  Re the comment about the canopy, Mark I Spits had a narrow canopy.  No framed greenhouse, but not blown out at the sides either.  The earliest Mark I Spits had a canopy that effectively was just an extension of the windscreen.  Later ones had a bulged top for more head clearance, but still had flat sides.  Later Marks featured the "blown" canopy that was bulged on the sides as well.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Answer (score 1):

It's a Hurricane. The radiator is on the fuselage, which means it is a Hurricane. On a Spitfire the radiator is on the right wing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Agree with qq jkztd.

Also the canopy.  You can just about make out the lines (in profile, it looks like a greenhouse) plus it's narrower.  A Spit's is more bulbous.

Comment: This is your 7th account. Please consider registering it and ask it to be merged with the previous ones. Follow the instructions here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts